# Flot: Legend updates only when the plotpan event occurs?

Tags: javascript, flot

The legend to my graph only occurs whenever the `plotpan` event occurs. Here is my `updateLegend` function found below which I am sure the program goes into of course using tracing messages

However, the only time the legend updates anymore since I included the `plotpan` functionality, is right after a `plotpan` occurs. I am unsure as to what is causing this, as such I am unable to address the problem. [Here is the JSFiddle that will be more helpful than the following isolated segment of code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzg3r/47/)

```
var updateLegendTimeout = null;
var latestPosition = null;
 function updateLegend(){
        var series = (plot.getData())[0];
        legends.eq(0).text(series.label ="x: " + (local_x)+" y: "+ (local_y));
 }  


placeholder.bind("plothover",  function (event, pos, item) {
if (item){
    local_x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2);
        local_y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
    console.log("x:" + local_x + ", " + "y:" + local_y);
}

if (!updateLegendTimeout){
    updateLegendTimeout = setTimeout(updateLegend, 50);
        updateLegendTimeout = null;
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly is this line of code intended to do?

```
legends.eq(0).text(series.label ="x: " + (x)+" y: "+ (y));
```

It seems to be assigning the series.label but I don't believe it's actually modifying the contents of the legend div.  It updates when you pan, though, because that forces a redraw of the grid (which redraws the legend).

The easiest fix is to call `setupGrid` manually after you change the legend.

```
function updateLegend(x,y){
  var series = (plot.getData())[0];
  var legends = $(placeholder_id+ ".legendLabel");
  series.label ="x: " + (x)+" y: "+ (y);
  plot.setupGrid();
  clearTimeout(updateLegendTimeout);
}
```

This is relatively expensive, though (redrawing the grid on every mouse move).  Another line of attack would be to manually set the text of the legend div but this might interfere with flots internal legend drawing.  If you really want to show the nearest point position, perhaps leave the legend alone and do it in a div of your own.

Finally, I'm not quite sure where you are going with all those `setTimeout`.  Seems like an over complication to me and you could simplify this quite a bit.

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzg3r/48/).

Comment: The timeouts are necessary, what I showed you was a toned down version of what I`m working on. I should have looked more carefully at what that line did, I was working from the Flot example with a dynamic legend, and copied that line from there.